# How to create a Map from a List with and inner list using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

so I have data classes like this:

```
data class Item(val name: String)
data class Order(val id: Int, val items: List<Item>)
```

and I have a list of Orders.

my question is, how can I create a map with Item name as key and list of Orders with that item as value using Kotlin's collections API?

Comment: `associateTo`/`associateBy` are your friends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that you have `orders: List<Order>`, you can first [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) the orders into pairs of `Order` and item name (so that each `Order` can occur multiple times if it has more than one `Item`), and then group these pairs by the item name using [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html), taking the orders from the pairs into the groups:

```
val result = orders
        .flatMap { o -> o.items.map { i -> o to i.name } }
        .groupBy({ (_, name) -> name }, valueTransform = { (o, _) -> o })
```

<sup>In the `groupBy` arguments, `{ (_, name) -> name }` is the grouping key selector function that takes the name from each pair, and `{ (o, _) -> o }` transforms the items when collecting them to the lists, it takes the order from the pair.</sup>

[(runnable demo of this code)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/cgfgl02bk2ptseu4r82ln8obh5/go30h3pacg3ptm2v2gmhld4s6r)

If you want to eliminate multiple occurences of the same `Order` in case it contains a single `Item` multiple times, use [`distinct`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html) as follows: `.flatMap { o -> o.items.distinct().map { i -> ... } }`

Comment: Thanks @hotkey! This definitely works! 
Now I wonder if we can have a simpler solution if we use associateTo/associateBy @Oliver Charlesworth mentioned.

Comment: @lawkai, I doubt it. The `associate*` functions can only transform a sequence of items into a map where each entry is somehow produced from one of the items. At least, I see no simple solution using `associate*` that would do the same. @OliverCharlesworth, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I misunderstood the OP's intent - `associate*` methods are unlikely to be helpful here :/